# Setting up Build Server to run NUnit Selenium Automated tests

Tags: c#, selenium, build, nunit, build-automation

I've been assigned a task of setting up a build server (jenkins) and running automated tests after the build agent completes the build.

We are using NUnit and selenium to run automated tests.

The main concern is wait time. Suppose several users check in their sources, a build is run and automated tests are run afterwards (there could be several hundred of these). What's the best way to set this up so that each user does NOT have to wait in queue for tests results. Also, I'm to consider things like test result reports etc.

Where do I start? What do I even google?

I'm very new at this stuff and any info on doing this would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: You will have to run them in parallel on different machines (whether physical or virtual), perhaps only run the smallest tests and leave longer running tests until the evening. I am not entirely sure running UI tests after every checkin is a good idea (this is the impression you've given). UI integration tests are always going to be inherently slow, it's the nature of the beast. Unless you have multiple boxes, you'll take up the CI server's time until it's finished. I set up ours (just over 100) to run in the evening. Solves the problem.

Comment: any info on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is to separate your unit tests from your integration tests.

Unit tests should be fast. Integration tests will obviously be slower since you're interacting with external components.

As far as configuring your environment, to do what you're trying to do properly, you'll need to research using Jenkins in a Master/multiple-Slave configuration. This isn't terribly complex, but can take some time to set up.

What you'll likely end up doing is setting up a number of Jobs within Selenium to handle each part of your build process. ie, one job to do the compilation, at least one job to run the unit tests, and at least one job to run the integration tests (and then maybe packaging or deployment jobs depending on how far you want to take this..).

Depending on how slow your overall build process is, you could easily have one job for each component's integration tests and run these concurrently on different slave machines. A parent job could would then aggregate the results and determine whether or not the chick-in passed.

For reporting, you'll want to install the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin), and the [NUnit Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin). These plugins will allow you to bundle the reports produced with the rest of the build artifacts.

In order to give feedback to your team, you'll also want to look at the [Wall Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Wall+Display+Plugin) to display the status of the jobs.